# Constraint on a related table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables (ItemType and Item). ItemType has a boolean `hasSize`, and the Item table has a `size` column.

I'd like to enforce that `size` is only set if the `hasSize` boolean = true.

I've seen solutions discussed which use triggers for validation. However, that doesn't provide the same robustness as a constraint.

Is this a problem of non-ideal schema design, or are there appropriate solutions for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check constraints cannot refer to other tables in the database & a trigger is a valid strategy around this limitation. I don't think your schema design is bad. Certain types of items are sizeable, and that information belong in the `item_type` table.

Here is an alternate solution not using triggers, where I impose a check constraint on an [UPDATABLE VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createview.html) to prevent data modification in the underlying tables, using the `WITH CHECK OPTION` modifier. **note that this will only validate if data inserted or updated through the view. You must grant appropriate permissions so that the application role cannot modify the `item` table directly, but can through the `UPDATABLE VIEW`**

Here's a self-contained script with sample data & examples insert that fails & insert that succeeds

```
-- set up dummy `item_type` table
CREATE TABLE item_type (
id int primary key generated by default as identity,
has_size bool,
name text not null unique
);
INSERT INTO item_type 
  (has_size, name) 
VALUES 
  (true, 'sizable type')
, (false, 'unisize');

-- set up dummy `item` table
CREATE TABLE item (
id int primary key generated by default as identity,
type_id int references item_type(id),
name text NOT NULL,
size text
);

INSERT INTO item
  (type_id, name, size)
VALUES
  (1, 'worlds best dad tee shirt', 'M')
, (2, 'usb key', NULL);

-- create updatable check view.
CREATE VIEW item_view AS
SELECT item.*
FROM item 
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 
FROM item_type 
WHERE item.type_id = item_type.id
  AND (item.size IS NOT NULL) = item_type.has_size
) 
WITH CASCADED CHECK OPTION; 
--    ^^^
-- i could have alternately used local 
-- instead of cascaded
```

This insert will fail

```
INSERT INTO item_view 
  (type_id, name, size) 
VALUES
  (2, 'dad socks', 'M');
```

It generates the following error:

```
ERROR:  new row violates check option for view "item_view"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, 2, dad socks, M).
```

This insert will succeed

```
INSERT INTO item_view 
  (type_id, name, size) 
VALUES
  (2, 'dad socks', NULL);
```

`SELECT * FROM item` returns the following result as expected

```
 id | type_id |           name            | size
----+---------+---------------------------+------
  1 |       1 | worlds best dad tee shirt | M
  2 |       2 | usb key                   |
  4 |       2 | dad socks                 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, it looks like an updateable view would definitely get closest to the ideal scenario. The only downside is that the creation of the view won't retrospectively validate any rows which would violate the check constraint. So only new INSERTs and UPDATEs would be validated (similar to a trigger).

Comment: @J3Y, You're right about the downside, however you can negate the predicates in the view creating query to flag all rows that do not match the constraint, and fix them before migrating the database to use the updatable view. I should add that if you enforcement of the constraints should be bi-directional, i.e. you should also set up an updatable view for `item_type` which would prevent updates to the field `has_size` if there are related `item`s

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'd call this a problem of the design. Normally such problems can be avoided by *not* storing `hassize`, since it can be derived when the database is queried.

Sometimes it is necessary to store redundant data to improve performance, but then you have to pay the price of potential inconsistency that you are afraid of.

If you cannot avoid persisting `hassize`, using a trigger is usually the best solution; try to avoid anomalies by reducing concurrency (e.g. locks or serializable isolation).

Comment: What do you mean by deriving `hasSize` when querying the database? My original intention was that the ItemType (for example clothing), would require related Items to have their size column set.

Comment: Right, then you can query the item type and determine this way if the size is set.